# increment 1 to the last elemet of array that is not 0 Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am new to JavaScript I am trying to get the last element of array that is not zero and add1 to it however my code is not giving desire output it is getting the last element even it is 0 and adding 1 to it

Example

[0,1,2,3,0,5,0,0,2,0]

result will be

[0,1,2,3,0,5,0,0,3,0]

2 is the last element that is not  zero increment by 1 = 3

code is

```
 var arr= [0,1,2,3,0,5,0,0,2,0];
 var lastItem = arr.pop();
 lastItem = lastItem+1;
 arr.push(lastItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet

```js
var arr= [0,1,2,3,0,5,0,0,2,0];
console.log("before",arr)
for(var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(arr[i] > 0)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i]+1;
        break;
    }
}
console.log("after",arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're after!

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0];
for (let x = arr.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
  let currElem = arr[x];
  if (currElem != 0) {
    arr[x] = arr[x] + 1;
    break;
  }
}
alert(arr);
```

It will iterate throughout your array in **reverse** and check each element, if it finds one that is **not** equal to zero (as per specification), it will add 1 and break.

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jzokdyf/)